# Verilog Bram sorting ram elements and rewrite them back

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am working on a verilog challenge. I have 16x8 BRAM named memory and its content randomly initialized from testbench. Then my top module named sort making sorting for this memory.
When we(write enable) is low and sort is high my sorting module should read the data from memory then write them back to memory as sorted.
My memory module as below.

```
    timescale 1ns / 1ps
module memory(clk, we, en, addr, di ,do);
    input clk;
    input we;
    input en;
    input  [3:0] addr;
    input  signed [4:0] di;
    output signed [4:0] do;
    reg signed [7:0] RAM [15:0];
    reg [2:0] read_addr;

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if(en)
        begin
            if(we)
                RAM[addr] <= di;
            read_addr <= addr;
        end

    end

    assign do = RAM[read_addr];
endmodule
```

And my sort module as below.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module sort(clk, we, en, addr, di, do, sort, done);
    input clk;
    input we;
    input en;
    input sort;
    input [3:0] addr;
    input  signed [4:0]di;
    output signed [4:0] do;
    output reg done;
    reg signed [7:0] RAM [15:0];
    reg signed [7:0] temp [1:0];
    integer i,j;

    memory mem(clk, we, en, addr, di, do);
    
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(we)begin
            RAM[addr] <= di;
        end
        else begin
        done <= 0;
            for(i=0; i<14; i = i+1) begin
                for(j=0; j<14-i; j = j+1) begin
                    temp[0] = RAM[j];
                    temp[1] = RAM[j+1];
                    if(temp[0] >  temp[1])begin
                        RAM[j] = temp[1];
                        RAM[j+1] = temp[0];
                    end
                end
            end
            done<=1;
        end
    end
  
endmodule
```

Finally my testbench as following.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module sort_tb();
    reg clk;
    reg en;
    reg we;
    reg sort;
    reg  [3:0] addr;
    reg  [4:0] di;
    wire [4:0] do;
    wire done;
    sort srt(clk, we, en, addr, di, do, sort, done);
    initial begin
        sort = 0; clk = -7; en = 1; we = 1; 
        addr = 0;  di = -8;   #10;
        addr = 1;  di = -5;   #10;
        addr = 2;  di = -6;   #10;
        addr = 3;  di = -3;   #10;
        addr = 4;  di = -4;   #10;
        addr = 5;  di = -1;   #10;
        addr = 6;  di = -2;   #10;
        addr = 7;  di = 1;    #10;
        addr = 8;  di = 0;    #10;
        addr = 9;  di = 3;    #10;
        addr = 10; di = 2;    #10;
        addr = 11; di = 5;    #10;
        addr = 12; di = 4;    #10;
        addr = 13; di = 7;    #10;
        addr = 14; di = 6;    #10;
        addr = 15; di = 8;    #10;
        we = 0;
        sort = 1;
         
        #10; 
        we = 1;
        sort = 0;
    end
    always #5 clk = ~clk;
endmodule
```

In the simulation screen I can see that my sort module work but I don't figure out how can I write this sorted data back to memory. And I know that my sorthing module does not work properly because it does not read data from memory direcly, it reads from directly di port.
Could you help me kindly in this issue?
Thank you.
My simulation result as below.(First ram belong to sort module and second ram belong to memory)[image]

[image]

Comment: There are two concepts of a ram model in the sort module, one structural and one behavioral.  Remove them both, replace with a dual port structural model.  Dedicate one port to the top level reads/writes and one port to reading and writing for the sort operations.  Use a state machine to control everything states: IDLE,WRITE-RAM-FROM-INPUT,SORT,READ-RAM-FROM-INPUT, maybe a couple more states for the details of the sort function.  Don't use blocking assignments in the synchronous always block, use non-blocking assignments.  Add a reset to the design.

Comment: As I undestand you refer a RAM someting like this [link]https://www.hizliresim.com/4pixo9r)

Comment: Another model of a dual port here around page 109.
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf

Comment: Actually, this document helped me a lot, as you said, I understood how to define dual ports. Thanks. I will try to complete the code. @Mikef